# Mongo DB: How to aggregate on self Collection to pull Value(s) associated to the IDs in Hierarchical Dataset

Tags: nosql

I'm trying to write an aggregation in Mongo which would result in something similar to SQL.

I'm now trying to achieve the same in Mongo with the above collection.

Please Suggest me how to build Mongo Aggregation in order to achieve my output.

Comment: In `module_child.data`, there is a document with field: `module_child_id`, is it correct behavior?

Comment: yes, `module_child.data.module_child_id` is linked to `module_details.data.module_child_id` updated the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unwind both `module_details` and `module_child` then match them.

```
[
  {
    "$unwind": "$module.module_details.data"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$module.module_child.data"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          "$module.module_details.data.module_child_id",
          "$module.module_child.data.module_child_id"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "module_id:": "$module.module_details.data.module_id",
      "name": "$module.module_child.data.name",
      "value": "$module.module_details.data.value"
    }
  }
]
```

You probably need to match on `module_id` as well. However, it was not a part of the question.

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "module_id": "9898"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$module.module_details.data"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$module.module_child.data"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          "$module.module_details.data.module_child_id",
          "$module.module_child.data.module_child_id"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "module_id:": "$module.module_details.data.module_id",
      "name": "$module.module_child.data.name",
      "value": "$module.module_details.data.value"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! this works for me and got an idea how to proceed with my dataset